# LINQ Conditional Sum

Tags: c#, linq, sum, where-clause

I have a model "fruit" storing the data like this:

```
date         fruit_code   count
2013/09/30   apple        10
2013/09/30   pear         5
2013/10/01   apple        1
2013/10/01   pear         2
2013/10/02   apple        5
```

All I want is to display the sum of the each fruit of each month, the output would be something like this:

```
date         no_of_apple   no_of_pear
2013/09      10            5
2013/10      6             2
```

I tried to build the linq like this but got stucked:

```
from o in fruit
let keys = new 
{ 
   date = o.date.ToString("yyyy/MM"),
   fruit = o.fruit_code
}
group o by keys into grp
select new 
{
   date = grp.Key.date,
   no_of_apple = // I got stucked here, wondering how to 
   no_of_pear = // calculate the conditional sum
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calculate the sum of the fruits and put them into a dictionary, then you can get the sum for each of the fruits.

Comment: you have to put the conditional Sum per code into the group keys statement to get the correct result, see the last edit of my answer...

Comment: **Your problem is not such simple** with only 2 kinds of `fruit`, you can have **unknown number** of fruit types. We can group them and return to some kind of structure and then **format** that structure to display what you want. However **formatting** depends on **what** control you use to display them...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = fruit.GroupBy(i => i.date)
            .Select(i => new
            {
                date = i.Key,
                no_of_apple = i.Where(j => j.fruit_code == "apple").Sum(k => k.count),
                no_of_pear = i.Where(j => j.fruit_code == "pear").Sum(k => k.count)
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you have two classes `Apple` and `Pear` derived from `Fruit`, and that they contain a `Count` property.

```
from o in fruit
let month = o.date.ToString("yyyy/MM") 
group o by month into grp
select new 
{
    date = grp.Key,
    no_of_apple = grp.OfType<Apple>.Sum(apple=>apple.Count),
    no_of_pear = grp.OfType<Pear>.Sum(pear=>pear.Count),
}
```

Comment: Where is this Apple and Pear type coming from? The OP is using a code to represent the type of fruit, not a separate type. (You should definitely not use a separate type for this kind of thing. A simple string would probably be better, or an enum)

Comment: It's just an assumption. In general when you say `Fruit` and `Apple` in sample code, you talk about derived classes. And I don't think a string would do a better job for that matter.

Comment: If you use a separate class for the type of fruit, then you will have created an application that needs to have new code written for it just because you are stocking a new kind of fruit. That's far from optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have grouped by the combination of date *and* fruit in the select you can only calculate the sum for that single fruit:

```
fruit_count = grp.Sum(o => o.count);
```

If you additionally capture the fruit in the select clause you end up with the result of the expression as a while being an enumeration of { date, fruit, count }.

This is then a better starting point for formatting. If you know you only have two types of fruit you can group by date and extract each fruit in turn for the columns. Otherwise initially extracting the set of fruit allows an inner loop, for each month, over the set of fruit (and remember, depending on the input data, a missing object is equivalent to a zero count).

Comment: You wrote `Sun` instead of `Sum`

Answer (score 0):

You can still do a comparision within the `.Sum` for the `Code` and then sum the `.Count` together

```
var result = from o in fruit
                group o by
                new
                {
                    date = new DateTime(o.Year, o.Month, 1),
                    Code = o.Code
                }
                into grp
                select new
                {
                    date = grp.Key.date,
                    no_of_apple = grp.Sum(p => p.Code == "apple" ? p.Count : 0), 
                    non_of_pear = grp.Sum(p => p.Code == "pear" ? p.Count : 0)
                };
```

There is only one issue, you'll get result rows for each month, one for *apple* one for *pear*, but maybe that's not really an issue...

:edit:
I think to really get what you wanted you'll have to restructure your group by a little bit and do the sum in there

```
var result = from o in fruit
                group o by
                new
                {
                    date = new DateTime(o.Year, o.Month, 1),
                    Code = o.Code,
                    no_of_apple = fruit
                        .Where(f => f.Month == o.Month && f.Year == o.Year)
                        .Sum(p => p.Code == "apple" ? p.Count : 0),
                    no_of_pear = fruit
                        .Where(f => f.Month == o.Month && f.Year == o.Year)
                        .Sum(p => p.Code == "pear" ? p.Count : 0)
                }
                    into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        date = grp.Key.date,
                        no_of_apple = grp.Key.no_of_apple,
                        no_of_pear = grp.Key.no_of_pear
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just group by month and count the apples/pears in the resulting select;

```
var v = from o in fruit
  group o by new {o.date.Year, o.date.Month} into grp
  select new 
  {
    date = grp.Key,
    no_of_apples = 
      (from a in grp where a.fruit_code == "apple" select a.count).Sum(),
    no_of_pears = 
      (from p in grp where p.fruit_code == "pear" select p.count).Sum(),
  };
```